# Adding author custom dimension to gtag.js tracking code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This is my first time using Stack Overflow for help but after exhausting my brain for weeks, I've been left with no choice but to ask for help.

A disclaimer: I have zero coding knowledge. I've somehow managed to keep my site afloat this long by following tutorials and camping on forums.

Now, to get to my problem.

I have a news website and I want to create custom reports on author pageviews on GA.

My tracking code is pasted on the header.php using "Insert Headers and Footers" plugin.

This is what my tracking code looks like:

```js
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-153194707-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-12345678-1');
</script>
```

On Analytics, I created a custom dimension for 'Author' with these settings:

1. Type: Hit
2. Status: Active

I have the dimension index but for the life of me, I do not know how to include the custom dimension into my code so that I can track the three authors' pageviews on my site.

Can you please help? And please be nice :)

Like I said, I have zero coding knowledge. like... Zilch.

Answer (score 0):

First at all if you dont have coding expirence take a look on the google Tagmanager. This tool is build for tracking without coding skills which is very nice

To your Question in the documentation from google is this cas not explained i wonder. the sense less link for you
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

But you can configurate your code before the config comes and send it by pageview

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-153194707-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
 function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
 gtag('js', new Date());
  

  gtag('set',
  {
    'custom_map':
      {
        'dimension<Index>': 'dimension_name'
      }
  });

 gtag('config', 'UA-12345678-1',{ 
      'dimension_name': 'author' });
</script>
```

**dimension_name** you have tor eplace with your name in analytics.
`<Index>` you have to replace with the index from analytics 1,2,3 etc

now it comes the problem in this code will the value in the methric allways be author
you have to change 'author' with a variable wich contains the author.
if you want select it with a javascript `document.querySelector('Selector').value`
or thomething like that. You have to be care the element is visible in the dom before the gtag('config'... will execute

You have to set the gtag('config... to set in a document ready function or put et simple with your plugin in the footer